# ¿Cómo animar el loader?

Tags: css3

Tengo el diseñado un loader pero como hago para que se anime.

```css
.mask {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #fff;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.loader {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 44px;
    margin: 23% auto 0 auto;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.spinner {
    border: 2px solid #eeeeee;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: .5em;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

.spinner {
    border-top-color: #417b03;
}
```

```html
<div class="mask" style="display: block;">
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="spinner"></div>
     Procesando...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear una animación de **CSS** usando `@keyframes` donde `0%` es el inicio de la animación y `100%` es el estado final de la misma, y la propiedad que vamos a animar es `transform: rotate()`

Una vez creada la animación puedes asignarla al evento usando la propiedad `animation` cuyo primer parámetro es el nombre que has dado a la animación seguido del tiempo de duración, el tipo de animación y el `loop` que en este caso lo haremos `infinite`.

Puedes ver mucha más información en [Usando animaciones CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Usando_animaciones_CSS)

Ejemplo funcional

```css
.mask {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #fff;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.loader {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 44px;
    margin: 23% auto 0 auto;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.spinner {
    border: 2px solid #eeeeee;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: .5em;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-animation: rotar 1s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: rotar 1s linear infinite;
    animation: rotar 1s linear infinite;
}

.spinner {
    border-top-color: #417b03;
}

@keyframes rotar {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mask" style="display: block;">
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="spinner"></div>
     Procesando...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola @CamiloVasquez gracias, es fantástico :)